# How to display images or information from database with a for looped radiobutton? in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

**Hello Everyone!** I have a problem displaying my images and information such as full name in my program. I have a for looped radiobutton and it counts as to how many candidates are running in a specific position. Example is "President".

Here is my code as of now :

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Position) FROM TableVote WHERE Position='" + "President" + "'", sc);
            Int32 PresCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            TxtPresCount.Text = PresCount.ToString();

            //int lol = Convert.ToInt32(TxtPresCount.Text);

            var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            panel.SuspendLayout();
            panel.Size = new Size(600, 150);
            panel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            panel.AutoScroll = true;
            panel.WrapContents = false;
            this.Controls.Add(panel);

            for (int i = 0; i < PresCount; ++i)
            {
                var radioButton = new RadioButton();
                radioButton.Size = new Size(75, 75);
                radioButton.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                radioButton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                panel.Controls.Add(radioButton);

                //radioButton.Image = Image.FromFile();
                radioButton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                radioButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            }
            panel.ResumeLayout();
```

as for the codes above, it counts all the President that is stored in the database. But my problem is, how do i put an image/Name that is stored in the database? Example i have 5 candidates running for the position of President, I want all the data to be in 5 radiobutton. How do i put the information into the radiobutton? Please help. :(

I add information using this code below :

```
    sc.Open();
        try
        {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVote (Position, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, YearLevel, Course, SchoolYear, imgPath, imgImage) VALUES (@position, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @yearlevel, @course, @schoolyear, @imgpath, '" + _pb + "')", sc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", _position);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearlevel", _yearlevel);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", _course);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgpath", _imgpath);

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(res > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
                FAdminSet._cleardata = cleardata;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
```

this is my database :

[image]

Comment: What information do you want to put into the radiobutton? **A RadioButton can hold only some Text** like a label, the difference is it allows some interaction to make choice.

Comment: Information such as Images, FullName of the candidate. Someone told me that it can hold images using `radioButton.Image`. But i don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: Where do you fetch the images from?

Comment: SqlServer 2008. Data Type is `Image`.

Comment: Is it stored in the table `TableVote`? You should show the table containing all the info of `candidates` for `president` including `FullName` and `Image`, I don't see any code you posted showing how to fetch `FullName` and `Image`

Comment: yes, that's my problem, what and where to put my codes.. is it inside the looping? and what should be my codes to fetch data from sql?

Comment: If you design your `Table` correctly, it's very simple to read and show the info in just one `while loop` using `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: can you please show me some example codes on how to fetch informations such as image and full name into 1 radiobutton? for each President count?

Comment: I can't because I don't know **your table structure**, I don't know **how you saved your image**, it's important to **build the query** and create the method for **reading image** correctly before we can use the info the put into some `RadioButtons`.

Comment: I edited my post, please i need to know how to fetch data and put it into 1 radiobutton.

Comment: The table structure is clear now, but it's still unclear on what kind of value for `Image` you put into your table, this `Param()` should be made clear. Normally, I store the images as `byte[]` using some `BinaryFormatter` to serialize them, the reading process is simply a `de-serialization`.

Comment: I posted my table in database and edited my Param

Comment: see my answer, if you have more question, just leave the comment and let me know how it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     //do this if you want to register the Load event handler using code
     Load += Form1_Load;
   }
   FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
   private void InitPanel(){
     panel.Size = new Size(600, 150);
     panel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
     panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
     panel.AutoScroll = true;
     panel.WrapContents = false;
     Controls.Add(panel);
   }
   //Load event handler
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
     InitPanel();
     panel.SuspendLayout();
     string cmdText = "SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) as FullName, " +
                 "imgPath as ImagePath FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'";
     using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdText,sc)){
       if(sc.State != ConnectionState.Open) sc.Open();
       SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();       
       while(reader.Read()){
         AddRadioButton(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
       }
       reader.Close();
       sc.Close();
       panel.ResumeLayout(true);
     }
   }
   private void AddRadioButton(string fullName, string imagePath){
     RadioButton radio = new RadioButton {Text = fullName, Parent = panel};
     radio.AutoSize = true;
     radio.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imagePath),75,75);
     radio.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;    
     radio.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;   
   }
}
```

**NOTE**: I can see that you store 2 info involving images in your table, I think you should choose 1 of them, storing `Image Path` is easy, light-weight for your table but the info may be lost if your `Image path` hasn't pointed to the actual image anymore.

Comment: base on my first few codes, how do i merge that code to your code? or should I erase my code and replace it with yours?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete now you can use my code, the code for initializing `panel` is kept intact.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete it's up to you, in `form_load` is OK. Note the `AddRadioButton` is a method, you have to put it in your form class.

Comment: sorry, but im kind of confused as to where i am going to put it. won't i be using my loop anymore?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete no, your loop requires to know the number of candidates, the code I posted is enough, just put it in your form_load and let me know if there is any exception...

Comment: in `private void AddRadioButton` Parent = panel.. panel does not exists in the current context.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete you should also declare your `panel` in your form class, not put it in your `form_load`.

Comment: it has no output. I put that codes into `form_load` and the `private void AddRadioButton` outside.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete is your `form_load` really `registered` with the event `Load` of your form? To debug better, you should add the `panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle` to see if you can see the border.

Comment: can you please add in your code what event should be and what code should be inside of it?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete no event is needed, I just want to mean **you should make sure all the code to be executed**, you place them in `form_load` method, that method should be registered with `Load` event of your form so that when your form is loaded, that triggers the event and runs the registered code in the handler. You can double click your form to **auto-generate** such a handler, put your code there. To register it manually, place this code in your form constructor `Load += (s,e)=> {//code goes here};`

Comment: **@LyndonBrozTonelete you should also declare your panel in your form class, not put it in your form_load. ** what do you mean by form class?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete it's your form, don't you have any form? it looks like this `public class Form1 : Form {   //..... here is everything of your form class }`

Comment: i tried putting in the declaration of flowlayoutpanel in `public void lol(){ // then the codes }` but when i call the method it does recognize the `panel`. i tried putting the declaration of flowlayoutpanel in class. it has many errors so i tried putting it in a method/function.

Comment: it does NOT recognize the panel ^

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I updated my code to make it **easier** for you

Comment: I added `panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;` but it has no output in my form when i run it.

Comment: i see the output now. but how do i adjust the images because i cant see the images?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete Try removing `SuspendLayout` in the `InitPanel`, at least when you call `InitPanel` successfully, the `panel` should be added with Size of `(600, 150)`

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete try executing the query in your `Sql Server Management` window, if there is no result, that's the problem. I'm pretty sure that the query **returns empty result**.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete you can't use the exact query as posted in my code to test in `SQL Server management window`, try this `SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) as FullName, imgPath as ImagePath FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'`

Comment: There are results.. Thank you i'm so happy bout that !! hehe.. but in the output when i run it, it wont show the pictures and how can control the radiobutton's size inside the panel?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete it won't show picture because the `imagePath` is wrong, you can check out the `imagePath` in your table and see if it points to some actual `image file`, if your `radioButton` shows Image OK, its size will be the size of the Image

Comment: coz i have 3 Presidents in my database. Then it automatically genereated 3 radiobutton inside the panel. But i see a little part of the picture in my 2nd radiobutton. not full sized

Comment: the Full name does not fit in the radiobutton text. How do i adjust the sizes of the radiobuttons inside the panel?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete you need `radio.AutoSize = true;` in `AddRadioButton` method, I also updated the code.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I think you also need to check out `radio.CheckAlign` to make the radiobuttons render horizontally better, see my updated code in `AddRadioButton` method.

Comment: thank you so much ! it works now! Can I ask for one last thing? if I want the radioButton click "the round thing that is clickable" to be at the bottom of the text, can it be possible?

Comment: `radio.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;` that solves it.. Thanks A lot @KingKing!

Comment: i would like to get the ID number of the selected radiobutton. is it possible?

Comment: so i can do voting count. I need to get the number of votes of the candidate running on the said position. how do i get the ID number too and pass it to another form and display the vote count there.