# How to get ID from database using my codes in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

**Hello Everyone**, I am having trouble in getting the vote count of my voting system. Whenever I click a radiobutton, I have to get the ID of that candidate and pass it to the other form to make a vote count. I am having trouble in making an event handler too. All of my controls are dynamic.

I have this code so far:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();

    private void InitPanel()
    {
        panel.Size = new Size(600, 150);
        panel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        panel.AutoScroll = true;
        panel.WrapContents = false;
        Controls.Add(panel);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitPanel();
        panel.SuspendLayout();
        string cmdText = "SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) as FullName, " +
             "imgPath as ImagePath FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'";
        using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdText,sc))
        {
            if(sc.State != ConnectionState.Open) sc.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();       
            while(reader.Read()){
            AddRadioButton(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }
        reader.Close();
        sc.Close();
        panel.ResumeLayout(true);
      }
   }

   private void AddRadioButton(string fullName, string imagePath)
   {
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton {Text = fullName, Parent = panel};
        radio.AutoSize = true;
        radio.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imagePath),75,75);
        radio.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;    
        radio.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;   
    }
   }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is how do i do a checkedchanged event in a dynamic radiobutton? and how do i get the ID of the candidate whenever a radiobutton is clicked?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I guess you'll have to ask fairly many more questions around this problem. Instead you should try programming with some simple problem first, from basic dealing with classes to dealing with database. Your problem now is also simple. You talked about the `ID` of the candidate, so where is it pulled from your `Table`? You have to pull the ids together with other information.

Comment: @KingKing yup i tried getting the id, but it gets all the ids of all president. I need it to be per candidate whenever a radiobutton is checked and pass the id to another form so i can perform vote counting.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I asked for where your ids are pulled from, BTW you should add some `Vote button` then handle the `Click` event of the `Vote button` instead, you don't need any `CheckedChanged` event handler for your `RadioButtons`

Comment: @KingKing yes, pulled from `table`. okay ill make a button for it, but what will i put in my `vote button`?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete I know they're pulled from your table but on What field? for example, the `full name` is pulled from your table on the field `FullName`...

Comment: @KingKing sorry i don't understand, right now my code is same as above, but i already added a `vote button`.

Comment: @KingKIng wher do i possibly pull it from? is it possible to pull it from `Position`? or ?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete what is your `position` for? If it can be used to identify the candidates, it's OK. But I guess your table doesn't have any ID, you should add such a column to your table. The ID is necessary because 2 candidates can have the same `Full name`, that's why `ID` is needed to identify them, there are more other reasons to use `ID` relating to `database design rule`.

Comment: @KingKing i have ID in my table (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332076/how-to-display-images-or-information-from-database-with-a-for-looped-radiobutton#)

Comment: @KingKing i Have `id` in my table `TableVote`, I want it to get the ID when i press the `Vote Button`, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define common checkchange event for all your dynamic radio button like this

```
 RadioButton radio = new RadioButton {Text = fullName, Parent = panel};
 radio.CheckedChanged += radio_CheckedChanged;
 radio.Tag=1;  //you can set here your own object.
```

Handle this event like this

```
void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var radio=(RadioButton)sender;
       int id=(int)radio.Tag;  //cast your object here 
    }
```

Hope this helps